# How can I automatically trust a Root CA in Firefox given a PEM file?

Tags: firefox, automation, ssl-certificate

I have:

- Firefox 24.0 on Windows 7 Enterprise
- A frequent need to have Firefox trust a specific Root CA in Base64-encoded "PEM" format on disk, e.g. `C:\foo.pem` (for instance)

  - The certificate I need to trust changes fairly often; this is in a development context, so I'm using self-signed certs, and for other reasons I am unable to use the same cert every time

I would like to automate the *results* of the following process in Firefox, using the command line *or* code (PowerShell, VBScript, C#, whatever is easiest):

- Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Certificates
- Click "View Certificates" button
- Click "Authorities" tab
- Click "Import..." button
- Select pre-determined PEM file location
- Check the three boxes for purposes to trust it for
- Click OK several times

If I *have* to automate this using the user interface itself, that would be OK... but **I would prefer not to have the UI automated**. Instead, I would prefer to have some *programmatic* way (a console program? a script?) that *does the same thing* without any UI interactivity by the user.

**Alternatively**, if Firefox can directly use the Windows Certificate Store (I don't believe it can, currently), and trust certificates that are stored there, that would be even better, because I already have a mechanism to import my changing root certificates into the Windows Certificate Store.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla and/or http://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/973496

Comment: And if you want to add the certificate to any new profile that is created: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/960707

Comment: Heh, after visiting the SO post you linked to at first, I noticed I had previously viewed that post and upvoted the question :) I don't have this problem anymore, and I'm glad I don't, because I don't think there's a way to do this on Windows while Firefox is running (since it locks cert8.db for writing while it's open).